# how to EC-CUBE3.0.15 upgrade into EC_CUBE4.1.0

Tags: symfony

I'm just try to **upgrade ec-cube3.0.15 to ec-cube4.1.0** but in both file structure in lot of different then can't get any success anyone can help to find out solution. It's easily to find upgrade serious into oven but try to **series 3 to series 4** into then not getting solution. please help me to find out this solution....
Thanks in advance
your faithfully friend.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to Symfony?

Comment: @NicoHaase can you check [symfony](https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/ec-cube/php/symfony)  and this another officially [link](https://doc4.ec-cube.net/customize_symfony).please help me to kick out this condition ...
thank you so much